# Swift get callback when UITextField.secureTextEntry changes it`s value

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am looking for a way to get a callback or an event when one of the UITextFields secureTextEntry changes the value.

The reason I need this is the following.

I extended the UITextField to have a functionality to toggle on and off the secureTextEntry via a button inside the UITextField. In one of my views I have two UITextFields and I want the button that controls the secureTextEntry state on the first UITextField to also change the secureTextEntry on the other UITextField. I think that the best way to do this is to get a callback in a view controllet itself and toggle the other UITextField but I cant find a way to get callback for UITextField.secureTextEntry change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the custom `UITextfield` class

```
override var isSecureTextEntry:Bool {
    didSet {
        // do next
    }
}
```

//

```
let myTextF = UITextField()
var myObserve:NSKeyValueObservation? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from  
     myObserve = myTextF.observe(\.isSecureTextEntry) { [weak self] (textF , change) in
       print("changed")
     }
}
```

Comment: How will I get a callback from this in my view controller though ?

Comment: And also it is not a custom UITextField class, it is a UITextField extension so I am not even sure if this override will work.

Comment: you can add an observer for that textfeilds's key

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Thanks Sh_Khan, I will give it a try right now.

Comment: Sh_Khan I am a bit lost here. Could you please clarify what do you mean by "you can add an observer for that textfeilds's key"? I have been searching for a way to do this for past 30 mins and I can`t find anything.

Comment: Who -1`ed the post lol. Atleast leave a a comment as to why you downvoted it.

Comment: Strange, I had that exact setup before and obserVealue still does not get called. didSet method is being called in custom UITextField but not the observeValue.

Comment: Now this is some sexy programming :) I really like the approach Sh_Khan, very short and readable code. One quick question though, do I need to invalidate myObserve when I am leaving the view or it will be handled automatically? Also myObserve should be a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: @Saik i added **[weak self]** to avoid strong references , you don't have to invalidate it

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. Create a protocol which will contain the function that will be used as callback whenever the isSecureTextEntry gets changed. have your ViewController conforms to that protocol when the function gets fired check which textfield and do what you want to do with other text field

Sample Code

CustomTextField.swift

```
import UIKit
protocol SecureEntryToggleDelagte {
    func didChangedSecureTextEntry(of textField: CustomTextField, isSecure: Bool)
}
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override var isSecureTextEntry: Bool{
        didSet{
            secureEntryDelegate?.didChangedSecureTextEntry(of: self, isSecure: isSecureTextEntry)
        }
    }
    var secureEntryDelegate: SecureEntryToggleDelagte?
}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldOne: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTwo: CustomTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFieldOne.secureEntryDelegate = self
        textFieldTwo.secureEntryDelegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func toggleTextFieldOne(_ sender: Any){
        textFieldOne.isSecureTextEntry = !textFieldOne.isSecureTextEntry
    }
    @IBAction func toggleTextFieldTwo(_ sender: Any){
        textFieldTwo.isSecureTextEntry = !textFieldTwo.isSecureTextEntry
    }

}
extension ViewController: SecureEntryToggleDelagte{
    func didChangedSecureTextEntry(of textField: CustomTextField, isSecure: Bool) {
        if textField == textFieldOne{
            print("textFieldOne isSecureTextEntry \(isSecure)")
        }else if textFieldTwo == textFieldTwo{
            print("textFieldTwo isSecureTextEntry \(isSecure)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I really like this approach Sahil. Thanks.

Comment: No need to attach **isSecure: Bool** you already can query the the first parameter for it

Comment: @Sh_Khan, I posted the answer at 1 AM :D might be the side effect.